# how javascript handles callback only with single thread?

Tags: javascript

as far as i Know, javascript uses single thread.

I am curious how eventHandler , ajax callback, fileReader callback works if javascript uses single thread.

can you guys tell me where can I can some detail information about eventHandler and how browsers

read and interpret javascript codes?

thanks in advance.

Comment: To avoid down votes, you should post where you searched, where to find information, google search is my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JavaScript code runs on a single thread (unless you're using Web workers), but that doesn't mean that the JavaScript engine is running a single thread. Ajax access executes on a separate thread and queues a call to the appropriate callback function when appropriate. The callback function is then called on the JavaScript thread.

Same thing goes with event handlers, file reader, and other asynchronous apis. The asynchronous work happens on other threads that the engine manages. However, those other threads are not calling your JavaScript code directly.